# Get duplicated Ids by grouping them

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-by, duplicates

I need to retrieve all the transactions that should have made a retry, depending on the message that the transaction received, for example, if we received an error message like "timeout" that transaction needs to make a second attempt. All the transactions are stored in a single table, meaning that if a payment id is duplicated, it means that the transaction made a retry, however, there are instances where this doesn't happen.

I wrote a query that pulls  the transactions with an error message and groups them
by payment id, the query works but it also brings transactions that made a second attempt.

What am I doing wrong?

```
   | payment_id | Bank  | time_requested | issuer      | message |attempt| 
   |   10369    | Citi  | 2021-08-03     | Capital One | success |   1   |
   |   10383    | HSBC  | 2021-07-07     | Discover    | success |   1   |
   |   84530    | HSBC  | 2021-07-07     | Visa        | timeout |   1   |
   |   84530    | HSBC  | 2021-07-07     | Visa        | success |   2   |
   |   53030    | Citi  | 2021-07-07     | Diners      | success |   1   |
   |   23930    | Citi  | 2021-07-07     | Diners      | timeout |   1   |

   select payment_id, count(payment_id) as times
   from paymentstbl
   where message in ('timeout', 'disconnected','unknown', 'Unavaialble')
   group by payment_id
   having times =1 

   Results:

   |   payment_id    | times  | 
   |    84530        | 1      |-- Wrong. Id 84530 is twice in the table
   |    23930        | 1      |-- Correct.
```

Comment: But the second one has a `message` of `success` and you are excluding the `success` messages :)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you don't actually care about the count and that the actual requirement is to identify payments that were not successful. If this is true, you can do this by identifying the last row for each `payment_id`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT pt2.*
FROM paymentstbl pt1
INNER JOIN paymentstbl pt2 ON pt2.payment_id = pt1.payment_id AND
                              pt2.attempt = (SELECT MAX(attempt)
                                             FROM paymentstbl
                                             WHERE payment_id = pt1.payment_id)
```

Once you have the last row, you can filter them to include only those which have one of your known error messages.

```
WHERE pt2.message IN ('timeout', 'disconnected', 'unknown', 'Unavaialble')
```

Alternatively, you can exclude those which were successful.

```
WHERE pt2.message != 'success'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for transactions with an error message without having any successful payment.If this is yes, you can try below query.

```
SELECT * from paymentstbl WHERE PAYMENTID NOT IN
(
    SELECT payment_id FROM paymentstbl WHERE message IN ('timeout', 'disconnected', 'unknown', 'Unavaialble')
    INTERSECT
    SELECT payment_id FROM paymentstbl WHERE message= 'success'
)
and MESSAGE IN ('timeout', 'disconnected', 'unknown', 'Unavaialble')
```

**Intersect** will put together those paymentid, which are successful and timeout/errored.

Now filter them to include only those which have the timeout/errored payment.

Answer (score -1):

i think, by giving or when do where clause can solve your problem.

```
select payment_id, count(payment_id) as times
   from paymentstbl
   where message in ('timeout', 'disconnected','unknown', 'Unavaialble') or attempt > 1
   group by payment_id
   having times =1
```

Comment: The OP thinks the result should be `84530 | 2` because they didnt realise that the second `84530` had a `message = success` which is not included in the selection, see `where message in ('timeout', 'disconnected','unknown', 'Unavaialble')` Your output does not even include the count and only includes those that have a  total of 1. I think you mis read the question I am afraid

Comment: yes, thank you for correction